# JSON parsing and checking condition on top of that

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below JSON output in python , I want to read through the list and find the value of "index" which is not equal to "alias": "R1_P1" and "alias": "W1_P1"  and store the value in a variable.
Also, also I want to make sure output index does not match with "alias": "R1_P1" index.

How do I achieve this.

```
[
  {
    "alias": "R1_P1",
    "index": "pI1"
   },
  {
    "alias": "W1_P1",
    "index": "pI1"
  },
  {
    "alias": "R1_S1",
    "index": "pI2"
  },
  {
    "alias": "W1_S1",
    "index": "pI2"
  }
]
```

The tried the this code for below step and is working fine:

```
a = {'R1_P1', 'W1_P1'}

for item in x:
    if item.get('alias', '').upper() not in a:
        print(item)
```

Output :

```
  {
    "alias": "R1_S1",
    "index": "pI2"
  },
  {
    "alias": "W1_S1",
    "index": "pI2"
  }
```

Now I want to check, index of "alias": "R1_S1"  or index of "alias": "W1_S1" does not match with index of "alias": "R1_P1".
i.e.

if index of "alias": "R1_S1"  or index of "alias": "W1_S1" == index of "alias": "R1_P1" then 
print("no") else print("yes")

Comment: At the risk of sounding pedantic, if you've parsed this JSON (a string) and created a dict, it's not JSON any more, it's just a list of dicts. I'd remove the `[json]` tag and terminology from the post, it might be confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array of `dicts` to a single `dict` and check the required conditions.

```py
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> # create an empty dict
>>> d = {}
>>> for x in chain(data):
...     a,b = list(x.values())
...     d[a] = b
...
>>> d
{'R1_P1': 'pI1', 'W1_P1': 'pI1', 'R1_S1': 'pI2', 'W1_S1': 'pI2'}
```

Now you can check the condition

```py
>>> if (d['R1_S1'] == d['P1_P1']) or (d['W1_S1'] == d['R1_P1']):
...     print("no")
... else:
...     print("yes")
```